# How to search for two strings in a text file and act on any of the two strings found using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have already a batch script to search for one string in a text file and send the file by email if string is found in file.

Now I have to search for two words. If anyone of the two strings is found,  the email should be sent.

I am using the below script, but it is sending the email even if none of the two words is found.

```
echo on
setlocal
sqlcmd -S admin\SQLEXPRESS -E -i C:\Process.sql >status.txt
set eMail=mailid@domain.com
set server=-server servername.domain.com
find "FAILED" status.txt && find "Slow" status.txt
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    blat status.txt -to %eMail% -f from -s "Text Found" %server%
)
```

How to search for two strings in a text file and act on any of the two strings found using batch script?

Comment: Please be very careful and precise about your problem description. Without testing, I would anticipate that your code would send a message only if BOTH "FAILED" AND "Slow" appeared in your `status.txt` file. I would suggest that you should replace your `find...` line with `findstr /L "FAILED Slow" status.txt`

Comment: @ mofi thanks for your suggestion, i did modified the title

Comment: Have you tried the solution I suggested?

Comment: @Magoo, yes i have tried it is working but i haven't used the /L is it fine , i am simply using findstr "FAILED Slow" status.txt, it is working

Comment: `/L` means a literal comparison. `/r` is the default, and is `regular-expression` comparison. In this case, it's not relevant, but I use `/L` from habit because people change the target string(s) and include characters like `.` which have a different meaning in regular expressions (`a character - any character`) from its meaning as a literal (`.`)

Comment: Yes i am also going to include the characters for the string like this <--FAILED--> and <--SLOW-->, any how thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the standard Windows console application `findstr` it is possible to specify multiple strings to find in a line combined with an OR expression, i.e. the exit code is `0` if there is a line found containing one of the strings to find, otherwise the exit code of `findstr` is `1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
sqlcmd.exe -S admin\SQLEXPRESS -E -i C:\Process.sql >"%Temp%\status.txt"
set "eMail=mailid@domain.com"
set "server=-server servername.domain.com"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:FAILED /C:Slow "%Temp%\status.txt" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 blat.exe "%Temp%\status.txt" -to %eMail% -f from -s "Text Found" %server%
del "%Temp%\status.txt"
endlocal
```

Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?` to get output the help for this console application.

`/L` specifies the search string should be interpreted as literal and not as regular expression strings case-sensitive because of missing option `/I`.

And with `/C:String` or `/C:"Another String"` one or more strings to search for can be specified on command line before the name of the file.

See also the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

For `<--FAILED-->` and `<--SLOW-->` as search strings as written in comment it is necessary to enclose the two search strings in double quotes as `<` and `>` are interpreted as redirection operators if not enclosed in a double quoted string.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"<--FAILED-->" /C:"<--SLOW-->" "%Temp%\status.txt" >nul
```

The last paragraph on last help page output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` lists all characters in a directory or file name which requires enclosing the name in double quotes which are space and `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. This requirement is in general also true for other parameter strings whereby the [redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) `|` and `<` and `>` must be added to list requiring enclosing double quotes. The redirection operators can't be used in a directory/file name. Therefore they are not listed in last paragraph of last help page of `cmd.exe` which belongs to paragraph above about directory/file name completion.

Comment: Yes this code working good, but a little change is we need to add double quotes (") for the file name , like this findstr /L /C:"FAILED" /C:"Slow". Thanks a lot Mofi

Answer (score 0):

Use `find "FAILED" status.txt && find "Slow" status.txt` to send mail only if BOTH terms exist in status.txt.

Use `find "FAILED" status.txt || find "Slow" status.txt` to send mail if EITHER term (or both terms) exist in status.txt.

The way you have your script now, it should not be sending mail if neither term exists. If it is, either one of the terms DOES exist in status.txt, or what you posted is not exactly what you've tested.